# Spatial join with polygon and multipolygon mixed feature class

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have a feature class which contains 300,000 polygon and multipolygon features in the same fc. The goal is to get a result layer of spatial join (must to be one to many join) between this feature class to itself and during the process I have to only use open source GIS software, better code than geoprocessing tools. I tried:

1. GeoPandas sjoin - doesn't have one to many option.
2. QGIS 1 - Tried to read the fc in QGIS then use join by location. The join crushed after 20%.
3. QGIS 2 - Tried to convert fc to shapefile then use multipart to singlepart than dissolve to get the first mix of polygon and multipolygon. Again the join crushed in the same time.

Mabye QGIS cannot handle this kind of geometries mix?

Comment: What kind of spatial relation are you after? Using QGIS' native SpatiaLite SQL support is okay?

Comment: 1. Desired spatial relation kind - intersect. 2. Think that is okay. It is qgis built in support?